# Getting access to parsed value after JSON parsing (embedded v8)

Tags: v8

I'm new to v8 and using 6.9.0.0 (latest).

After I do something like the following:

```
v8::Local<v8::Value> parsed = v8::JSON::Parse(context,buffer1).ToLocalChecked();
```

How do I access the parsed pairs (like parsed.parameter1 in JS)? The straightforward addressing doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the various functions on V8's API:

For example, `v8::Local` has `IsObject()`, when that returns `true` you can create a `v8::Local<v8::Object> obj = v8::Local<v8::Object>::Cast(parsed);`, and `v8::Object` has e.g. `GetOwnPropertyNames` and `Get` and so on.

In short, V8's API provides a C++ implementation of the JavaScript object model. It's a bit unwieldy to work with, that's because the JS object model is so different from C++'s.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any kind of guideline for different aspects of this other than just API reference?

Comment: There's the ECMAScript spec, which is mostly reflected in V8's API (e.g. `GetOwnPropertyNames`). There's the API itself, including its embedded documentation (rendered to HTML e.g. at https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-10.6/ ). And there is some example code in V8's samples/*.cc and test/cctest/test-api.cc.